# Spark add column to dataframe when reading csv

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a csv with data shaped like this :

```
0,0;1,0;2,0;3,0;4,0;6,0;8,0;9,1
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;3,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;4,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;5,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;6,0;1,0;"BC"
```

I want to convert it into a dataframe with the last column named "value". I already wrote this code in Scala :

```
val rawdf = spark.read.format("csv")
                 .option("header", "true")
                 .option("delimiter", ";")
                 .load(CSVPATH)
```

But I get this result with a `rawdf.show(numRows = 4)` :

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|0,0|1,0|2,0|3,0|4,0|6,0|8,0|9,1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|4,0|2,1|2,0|1,0|1,0|0,1|3,0|1,0|
|4,0|2,1|2,0|1,0|1,0|0,1|4,0|1,0|
|4,0|2,1|2,0|1,0|1,0|0,1|5,0|1,0|
|4,0|2,1|2,0|1,0|1,0|0,1|6,0|1,0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

How can I add the last column on spark? Should I just write it on the csv file?

Comment: For the records, the different options that can be applied to a DataFrameReader : [go to line 356](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without changing the CSV file, you set the schema in your code:

```
val schema = StructType(
    Array(
        StructField("0,0", StringType),
        StructField("1,0", StringType),
        StructField("2,0", StringType),
        StructField("3,0", StringType),
        StructField("4,0", StringType),
        StructField("6,0", StringType),
        StructField("8,0", StringType),
        StructField("9,1", StringType), 
        StructField("X", StringType)
    )
)

val rawdf = 
    spark.read.format("csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("delimiter", ";")
        .schema(schema)
        .load("tmp.csv")
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! Out of Curiosity, what is the `true` parameter for?

Comment: The third argument is `nullable`. It's got a default value (`true`) so I'll remove that since it's not really relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Spark tries to map the data columns based on available number of header columns that you have if you set :

```
.option("header", "true")
```

You can resolve this issue in one of the below 2 ways :

1. setting header = false
2. Adding the header column for the last data column or by just adding a semicolon(;) at the end of the header line.

eg:

```
0,0;1,0;2,0;3,0;4,0;6,0;8,0;9,1;
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;3,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;4,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;5,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;6,0;1,0;"BC"
```

OR

```
0,0;1,0;2,0;3,0;4,0;6,0;8,0;9,1;col_end
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;3,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;4,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;5,0;1,0;"BC"
4,0;2,1;2,0;1,0;1,0;0,1;6,0;1,0;"BC"
```

Comment: So I have to change my csv file if I want a header with the last column?

Comment: Actually setting header = false does not solve the issue, as the first line of the csv (the header) is missing one column, so spark ignores the last column on the next lines.

Comment: Yes add a column in the header. It should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't know the length of lines of data** then you can read it as `rdd`, do some *parsings* and then create a *schema* to form a `dataframe` as below

```
//read the data as rdd and split the lines 
val rddData = spark.sparkContext.textFile(CSVPATH)
    .map(_.split(";", -1))

//getting the max length from data and creating the schema
val maxlength = rddData.map(x => (x, x.length)).map(_._2).max
val schema = StructType((1 to maxlength).map(x => StructField(s"col_${x}", StringType, true)))

//parsing the data with the maxlength and populating null where no data and using the schema to form dataframe
val rawdf = spark.createDataFrame(rddData.map(x => Row.fromSeq((0 to maxlength-1).map(index => Try(x(index)).getOrElse("null")))), schema)

rawdf.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_7|col_8|col_9|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|0,0  |1,0  |2,0  |3,0  |4,0  |6,0  |8,0  |9,1  |null |
|4,0  |2,1  |2,0  |1,0  |1,0  |0,1  |3,0  |1,0  |"BC" |
|4,0  |2,1  |2,0  |1,0  |1,0  |0,1  |4,0  |1,0  |"BC" |
|4,0  |2,1  |2,0  |1,0  |1,0  |0,1  |5,0  |1,0  |"BC" |
|4,0  |2,1  |2,0  |1,0  |1,0  |0,1  |6,0  |1,0  |"BC" |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful